# AlertDialog looks differently on Nexus devices

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, textcolor, alertdialogpro

I'm creating different AlertDialogs in different scenarios in my application using the following code:

```
public static void showAlertDialog(Context activityContext, DialogType type, CharSequence title, CharSequence msg, CharSequence posText,
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener posOnClickListener, CharSequence negText, DialogInterface.OnClickListener negOnClickListener, boolean isCancelable, int iconResId) {
    try {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activityContext);
        if (JavaUtils.isNotNullNotEmptyNotWhiteSpaceOnly((String) title))
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
        if (JavaUtils.isNotNullNotEmptyNotWhiteSpaceOnly((String) msg))
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(msg);
        if (JavaUtils.isNotNullNotEmptyNotWhiteSpaceOnly((String) posText))
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(posText, posOnClickListener);
        if (JavaUtils.isNotNullNotEmptyNotWhiteSpaceOnly((String) negText))
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(negText, negOnClickListener);

        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(isCancelable);

        // set alert icon
        if (iconResId == 0) {
            alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(type == DialogType.ERROR ? android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert : android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
        } else {
            alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(iconResId);
        }

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        alertDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        InfiLogger.w("showAlertDialog", e.toString(), e);
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
    }
}
```

While on most devices that run `Lollipop` or higher the `AlertDialog` looks like this:

[image]

On `Nexus` devices the same running code looks like this:

[image]

Does someone knows why this happens? And what is the proper way to fix this?

Comment: What are you passing in as `Context activityContext`?

Comment: @CommonsWare, in case of this specific AlertDialog the passed context is an Activity that extends FragmentActivity.

Comment: This feels like a theme problem. Since you need it anyway to handle configuration changes, I suggest that you move this stuff out of a `static` method and into a `DialogFragment`, and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare, didn't understand what you mean by "move this stuff out of a static method and into a DialogFragment". How can I move it into the DialogFragment?

Comment: Create a subclass of `DialogFragment`. Override `onCreateDialog()`; in there is where your `AlertDialog.Builder` code goes. Then, use the `DialogFragment` to show the dialog. See [the full docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) and [the backport that you would use](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html). See also [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Dialogs) (though it uses native fragments, not the backport as you are using).

Comment: Ok, I will try to move it to DialogFragment and update you with the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this problem is using the `AlertDialog` from the support library instead of using the original one.

So all I had to do to solve this issue was to replace this import:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

with this import:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```